# What is the proper way to handle site requests with cookie handlers in Python3?

Tags: python, httpwebrequest, python-3.x, urllib

I'm writing a script in Python 3.1.2 that logs into a site and then begins to make requests. I can log in without any great difficulty, but after doing that the requests return an error stating I haven't logged in. My code looks like this:

```
import urllib.request
from http import cookiejar
from urllib.parse import urlencode

jar = cookiejar.CookieJar()

credentials = {'accountName': 'username', 'password': 'unenc_pw'}
credenc = urlencode(credentials)

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
req = opener.open('http://www.wowarmory.com/?app=armory?login&cr=true', credenc)
test = opener.open('http://www.wowarmory.com/auctionhouse/search.json')
print(req.read())

print(test.read())
```

The response to the first request is the page I expect to get when logging in.

The response to the second is:

```
b'{"error":{"code":10005,"error":true,"message":"You must log in."},"command":{"sort":"RARITY","reverse":false,"pageSize":20,"end":20,"start":0,"minLvl":0,"maxLvl":0,"id":0,"qual":0,"classId":-1,"filterId":"-1"}}'
```

Is there something I'm missing to use any cookie information I have from successful authentication for future requests?

Comment: I get exactly the same response hitting the second URL both in Chrome and from curl. Do you have reason to believe the first URL should log you into the 2nd? (BTW, is it really supposed to be '?app=armory?login&cr=true'?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue once. I can't get the cookie the cookie management working automatically. Frustrated me for days, I ended up handling the cookie manually. That is getting the content of 'Set-Cookie' from the response header, saving it somewhere safe. Subsequently, any request made to that server, I will set the 'Cookie' into the request header with the value I got earlier.